# I cannot run more than 4 threads on an i5 CPU?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu, hardware

I have made a program that is running 5 threads simultaneously. These 5 threads each will be running multiple time-consuming operations that can last around 3 hours in total.

Before the 2 hour mark, the UI seems to run fine. But I have discovered that after around 2 hours has passed, the UI becomes unresponsive and lags. 
Furthermore, the results from the 5th thread becomes wrong or have bogus value. I have tried my best in optimising my coding but this still happens.

My company computer has an i5-6500 CPU and 8 GB of RAM. I have checked online that this CPU can only run 4 threads at a time. To run 5 or more threads, an i7-7700 with hyperthreading will be needed which can run 8 at a time.

Am I right about this hardware limitation? Or is there something I can do with my C# coding to overcome this problem? FYI, I'm using BackgroundWorker to handle my multithreading.

I have to confirm that it is absolutely a hardware problem before proposing to my boss that the company has to invest in a new CPU and motherboard.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. :)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(string.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "\\limit.txt"), true))
       {
          String input; //read value limits from textfile and storing it in array
          int i = 1;
          while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
             {
                limit_memory[i]= input;
                i++;
             }
        }
    }

}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //shows some textboxes that user has to fill and press enter to continue
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //shows some textboxes that user has to fill and press enter to continue
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //shows some textboxes that user has to fill and press enter to continue
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //shows some textboxes that user has to fill and press enter to continue
}
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //shows some textboxes that user has to fill and press enter to continue
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
      {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
           {
              object[] button1_var = { sentry1, terminal1, txtBox1_serial};
              backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(button1_var); //pass some arguments with an object
           }
      }
}

private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
      {
        if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy != true)
           {
              object[] button2_var = { sentry2, terminal2, txtBox2_serial};
              backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync(button2_var); //pass some arguments with an object
           }
      }
}
private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
      {
        if (backgroundWorker3.IsBusy != true)
           {
              object[] button3_var = { sentry3, terminal3, txtBox3_serial};
              backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerAsync(button3_var); //pass some arguments with an object
           }
      }
}
private void textBox4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
      {
        if (backgroundWorker4.IsBusy != true)
           {
              object[] button4_var = { sentry4, terminal4, txtBox4_serial};
              backgroundWorker4.RunWorkerAsync(button4_var); //pass some arguments with an object
           }
      }
}
private void textBox5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
      {
        if (backgroundWorker5.IsBusy != true)
           {
              object[] button5_var = { sentry5, terminal5, txtBox5_serial};
              backgroundWorker5.RunWorkerAsync(button5_var); //pass some arguments with an object
           }
      }
}
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  try
    {
      //uses the arguments passed and perform long operations
      //prints results to textFile1
    }
  catch
    {
      throw new BackgroundWorkerException(sernum, ex);//pass the unit's serial number to the error handler
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  try
    {
      //uses the arguments passed and perform long operations
      //prints results to textFile2
    }
  catch
    {
      throw new BackgroundWorkerException(sernum, ex);//pass the unit's serial number to the error handler
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  try
    {
      //uses the arguments passed and perform long operations
      //prints results to textFile3
    }
  catch
    {
      throw new BackgroundWorkerException(sernum, ex);//pass the unit's serial number to the error handler
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker4_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  try
    {
      //uses the arguments passed and perform long operations
      //prints results to textFile4
    }
  catch
    {
      throw new BackgroundWorkerException(sernum, ex);//pass the unit's serial number to the error handler
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker5_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  try
    {
      //uses the arguments passed and perform long operations
      //prints results to textFile5
    }
  catch
    {
      throw new BackgroundWorkerException(sernum, ex);//pass the unit's serial number to the error handler
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //updates the UI on what operations are being run
}
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //updates the UI on what operations are being run
}
private void backgroundWorker3_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //updates the UI on what operations are being run
}
private void backgroundWorker4_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //updates the UI on what operations are being run
}
private void backgroundWorker5_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //updates the UI on what operations are being run
}
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled == true) //if user cancels thread
    {
     //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
  else if(e.Error != null) //if error occurs in thread
    {
     string sernum = ((BackgroundWorkerException)e.Error).Sernum;
     //logs the serial number and error into a log text file
    }
  else //the program ends normally
    {
      //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled == true) //if user cancels thread
    {
     //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
  else if(e.Error != null) //if error occurs in thread
    {
     string sernum = ((BackgroundWorkerException)e.Error).Sernum;
     //logs the serial number and error into a log text file
    }
  else //the program ends normally
    {
      //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker3_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled == true) //if user cancels thread
    {
     //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
  else if(e.Error != null) //if error occurs in thread
    {
     string sernum = ((BackgroundWorkerException)e.Error).Sernum;
     //logs the serial number and error into a log text file
    }
  else //the program ends normally
    {
      //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker4_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled == true) //if user cancels thread
    {
     //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
  else if(e.Error != null) //if error occurs in thread
    {
     string sernum = ((BackgroundWorkerException)e.Error).Sernum;
     //logs the serial number and error into a log text file
    }
  else //the program ends normally
    {
      //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
}
private void backgroundWorker5_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Cancelled == true) //if user cancels thread
    {
     //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
  else if(e.Error != null) //if error occurs in thread
    {
     string sernum = ((BackgroundWorkerException)e.Error).Sernum;
     //logs the serial number and error into a log text file
    }
  else //the program ends normally
    {
      //disconnect unit from PC, clears UI
    }
}
public class BackgroundWorkerException : Exception //to pass serial number to error handler
    {
        public string Sernum { get; set; }

        public BackgroundWorkerException(string sernum, Exception ex)

        {
            Sernum = sernum;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Added coding to show how I structure my Backgroundworker.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159405/discussion-on-question-by-user107257-i-cannot-run-more-than-4-threads-on-an-i5-c).

Answer (score 2):

i5-6500 got 4 hardwarethreads, which means that the usage of the core got splittet and optimized to 4 threads. You can start as many treads as you want on every CPU, but then they will run like: 
**Singlecore example:**

> start A, stop A, start b, stop b, start a again, stop a, starb b
>   again.

Comment: I'm using BackgroundWorker to handle the multithreading. It is suppose to optimise on how the sequences of these threads work right? But my UI will still become unresponsive.

Comment: So now you know it´s possible that it can run normally. If you want more then post your code and handler/...

Comment: That highly depends on how you are using those BGWs. You can still mess up responsiveness.

Comment: @LenglBoy I haved some coding. Hope it gives a clearer picture without it being too complicated.